# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter customize times

Tags: ios, audio, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have an app with a continuous streaming. I want to know how to set the remaining time to 0:00 like tuneIn does, also how to set the playback duration for a continuous streaming on MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.

Here is a screenshot of the TuneIn radio[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the `"MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration"`?

Comment: Yes.. but it does not set the remaining time to 0:00.. This just works for known duration of a track..

Comment: What duration did you set it to?

Comment: I put a random value, like 10, to test it.. But is the remaining time that I want to set to 0:00.. not the elapsed time

Comment: So you didn't try setting it to `Float.infinity` or `0.0` or any weird extreme values like that?

Comment: yes.. but I get the elapsed time --:-- , and remaining time --:--